# Add change event to all cells in specified column of Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to add a change event to all cells in a specified column using Kendo UI. Something like:

```
 this.myGridVariable.table.on("change", "--InsertMyColumnNameHere--", (e) => { this.doStuff(e) });
```

I thought this worked:

```
 this.myGridVariable.table.on("change", "[name=ColumnName]", (e) => { this.doStuff(e) });
```

but it doesn't, at least not with the latest update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify what change event you mean:

- The HTMLElement change event in JavaScript, which is fired for `<input>`, `<select>`, and `<textarea>`, but not a table cell, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event
- The Kendo Model or DataSource change event documented here: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/change

I believe you'll want the second one. You can't bind it to a single field, but it has `e.field` and you can execute code depending on its value.

Answer (score 0):

add `.Events(e => { e.Change("onEdit"); })` under `.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource`

`onEdit` is a javascript function. In this function add this code -->
`function onEdit(e) { if (e.action == "itemchange") {   doStuff } }`